# react-native-fbsdk-next's LoginManager.logOut() does not logout a user

Tags: firebase, react-native, react-native-fbsdk

I am using react-native-fbsdk-next to connect Facebook Auth in the react native app.
I am using 'LoginManager.logOut()' code to logout a user.

After logging out, if another user tries to log in again then app does not ask for the username and password again. How can I log out a user from the app? I am not logged in to the Facebook account on this device.

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: No, I could not find the solution.

Comment: just clear the token in your app, you don't need to use ```LoginManager.logOut()```.  It's specifically stated in the documentation that this method may not work at times. https://github.com/invertase/react-native-apple-authentication#4-implement-the-logout-process